# FormatCurrency is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, format-currency

I am trying to convert textbox value on onblur event to a `$` currency using `jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.js` and my **javascript** function looks as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.currency').blur(function()
    {
        $('.currency').formatCurrency();
    });
});
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="textbox"  id="currencyField" class="form-control currency" placeholder="Enter Price"/>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: possible (and most common) reasons .... you didn't include the plugin script, or path is wrong , or you are loading jQuery.js more than once in page

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.js"></script>

Comment: check in browser dev tools network to see if that script is loading and make sure jQuery isn't being loaded again after it

Comment: thanks for response....i am using right path and there are no jquery.js duplicates

Comment: you are sure it is loading? The error means that the function doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code work fine, you have just to add the `jquery-formatcurrency` library :

https://jquery-formatcurrency.googlecode.com/files/jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.min.js

Or download it will be better **since googlecode.com is being deprecated** like @charliefl mentioned in comment bellow.

See the implementation in fiddle **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/44/)**.

Comment: would suggest downloading it since `googlecode.com` is being deprecated and isn't a CDN